# Using Facebook's Graph API for "Liked by" Type Searches

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can the Facebook Graph API be used to make search queries such as
`pages liked by people that like {topic|page|etc}`

I've been going through the documentation and can only find ways to search keyword strings, and specify type (page, person, place, location, etc.) But can't find mention of any specific means.

I've tried the following:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/search?q=pages%2Cliked%2Cby%2Cpeople%2Cwho%2Clike%2Cpage&type=page&access_token=xxx`

But, as expected, it produced an empty dataset—not an error.

Is there a way to make such a request through graph api? Or is that specific type of functionality reserved for manual searches?

Comment: No, that is not possible. Graph Search can only be used by users via the FB UI, there is no API for that.

Comment: Thanks, I resigned myself to other methods than the official graph API